# No Activity methods on FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have class extended from `AppCompatActivity` which extended from `FragmentActivity`.

I have fragments where I call `getActivity()` method to do some things, like `setTitle()`.

After using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 I noticed following problem: 
IDE marks as error

> cannot resolve method

to **all** methods which is not overridden or not exists in `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` like `setTitle()`, `runOnUiThread()` and many others.

But project builds and compiles without any errors.

**Question** how to solve this problem?

**What I tried**

1. Invalidate caches and restart

**Update** have no idea why you need code for abstract problem, but

```
public class FullViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_view); 
      setTitle("test"); //method is not resolved
      getIntent(); //method is not resolved
   }
}
```

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra posted. But have no idea how code can help with obvious IDE problem. Especially when this code works and no marks were detected in previous version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been around for a while, and is usually due to outdated support library versions.

If you follow the class hierarchy for `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, you will see that it does extend from `android.app.Activity`. But along the way there's an interesting annotation on the `android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity` class which is likely causing your issue. It has an annotation called `@RestrictTo` which is intended to restrict access to a specific set of classes (with a different kind of granularity compared to the default java visibility constructs). **But** in this case, that annotation is likely blocking your ability to access ALL methods from the `SupportActivity` and all subclasses (ie `Activity`).

I was able to fix this by simply updating my appcompat to the latest version (25.3.1 at time of writing). The original version had a group of `GROUP_ID` which was later changed to `LIBRARY_GROUP`. I suspect the way android studio processed these annotations is the source of your issue.

There is a resolved version of this issue on the android studio bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130193

Comment: Yes! That helped! I changed build tools version to 25.0.3 and that helped. Btw are you sure about 25.3.1? Depends on here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html latest is 25.0.3. Anyway you helped a lot, thanks.